# Parallel optimizations in SciPy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have a simple function

```
def square(x, a=1):
    return [x**2 + a, 2*x]
```

I want to minimize it over `x`, for several parameters `a`. I currently have loops that, in spirit, do something like this:

```
In [89]: from scipy import optimize

In [90]: res = optimize.minimize(square, 25, method='BFGS', jac=True)

In [91]: [res.x, res.fun]
Out[91]: [array([ 0.]), 1.0]

In [92]: l = lambda x: square(x, 2)

In [93]: res = optimize.minimize(l, 25, method='BFGS', jac=True)

In [94]: [res.x, res.fun]
Out[94]: [array([ 0.]), 2.0]
```

Now, the function is already vectorized

```
In [98]: square(array([2,3]))
Out[98]: [array([ 5, 10]), array([4, 6])]

In [99]: square(array([2,3]), array([2,3]))
Out[99]: [array([ 6, 12]), array([4, 6])]
```

Which means it would probably be much faster to run all the optimizations in parallel rather than looping. Is that something that's easily do-able with SciPy? Or any other 3rd party tool?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to optimize: your function returns two values. By the way the first one is a parabola, the minimum is zero, the second has no minimum

Comment: Check out the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.11.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize), in particular, note the implications of `jac = True`.  The function is returning both the "cost" and the gradient.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you looking for a solution for this specific simple function or for any simple function?

Comment: looking for solution to this problem for any given function. This example is just a trivial illustration.
my real problem is trying to implement a multiclass classification algorithm. i am currently looping through each class and minimizing the cost function one time per class. But my cost function can easily return a vector of costs and a vector of gradients but i am trying to find out how to feed that to scipy.optimize.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's another try, based on [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12874964/1015178) and the discussion that followed.

As far as I know,  the [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) module is for functions with scalar or vector inputs and a scalar output, or "cost".

Since you're treating each equation as independent of the others, my best idea is to use the multiprocessing module to do the work in parallel.  If the functions you're minimizing are as simple as the ones in your question, I'd say it's not worth the effort.

If the functions are more complex, and you'd like to divide the work up, try something like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from multiprocessing import Pool

def square(x, a=1):
    return [np.sum(x**2 + a), 2*x]

def minimize(args):
    f,x,a = args
    res = optimize.minimize(f, x, method = 'BFGS', jac = True, args = [a])
    return res.x

# your a values
a = np.arange(1,11)

# initial guess for all the x values
x = np.empty(len(a))
x[:] = 25

args = [(square,a[i],x[i]) for i in range(10)]
p = Pool(4)
print p.map(minimize,args)
```

Answer (score 15):

I am a bit late to the party. But this may be interesting for people who want to reduce minimization time by parallel computing:

We implemented a parallel version of `scipy.optimize.minimize(method='L-BFGS-B')` in the package **[optimparallel](https://pypi.org/project/optimparallel/)** available on PyPI. It can speedup the optimization by evaluating the objective function and the (approximate) gradient in parallel. Here is an example:

```
from optimparallel import minimize_parallel
def my_square(x, a=1):
    return (x - a)**2
minimize_parallel(fun=my_square, x0=1, args=11)
```

Note that the parallel implementation only reduces the optimization time for objective functions with a long evaluation time (say, longer than 0.1 seconds). Here is an illustration of the possible parallel scaling:
[image]

Comment: where you specify the number of processors?

Comment: @andy see the description of the `parallel` argument.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your intent, you can pass numpy arrays for both `x` and `a`, so you can optimize for all your `a` parameters at once.

Try something like:

```
def square(x, a=1):
    return [np.sum(x**2 + a), 2*x]

# your a values
a = np.arange(1,11)

# initial guess for all the x values
x = np.empty(len(a))
x[:] = 25

# extra arguments to pass to the objective function, in this case, your a values
args = [a]

res = optimize.minimize(square, x, method = 'BFGS', jac = True, args = args)
```

This appears to be getting the correct results.

```
>>> res.x
[ -8.88178420e-16  -8.88178420e-16  -8.88178420e-16  -8.88178420e-16
  -8.88178420e-16  -8.88178420e-16  -8.88178420e-16  -8.88178420e-16
  -8.88178420e-16  -8.88178420e-16]
>>> res.fun
55.0
```

Comment: i guess that was just too intuitive for me. will try to implement on my real problem and let you know how it goes. thanks!

Comment: what version of scipy are you using? I actually get a ValueError trying to run that code: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Sorry @ludaavics, I was using an older version of scipy (0.10) and extrapolating, which i shouldn't have done.  I've tested the above with scipy 0.11 and it works. The difference is that the "cost" value must be a scalar. The version I was using seemed to be doing this implicitly by summing the cost vector that `square` returned.

Comment: ok so this approach would not work for my purposes, yes? i guess the example i took was a bit too simplistic -- if you change cost function to be `(x+a)**2`, so that different parameter give different location of the minimum, summing the cost vector becomes meaningless (which i guess is why in 0.11 they force you to return a scalar to make that clear)

Comment: Ok, maybe I totally misunderstood your intent.  Am I correct that you're trying to find the scalar value `x` which minimizes the output of `square()` given a scalar input `a`, but each equation is independent of all the others?

Comment: that's exactly what i am trying to do.

Comment: actually i am trying to find the *vector* `x` where the i-th element is the scalar that minimizes the output of `square()` given the i-th element of vector `a`. 
each element on the output `x` will be entirely determined by the corresponding element in `a`