# how to optimize the minimization of a vector function in python?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have an issue: I'm trying to find the minimum of a function which depends on several parameters that I'd like to change as well. let's take as a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
def f(x, a, b, c):
    f = a * x**2 + b * x + c
return f
```

I'd like to find the x which minimizes the function for different set of values of a, b, c, let's say for

```
a = [-1, 0, 1]
b = [0, 1, 2]
c = [0, 1]
```

ATM I have three nested loops and a minimization:

```
for p1 in a:
    for p2 in b:
         for p3 in c:
            y = opt.minimize(f, x0=[0, ], args=(p1, p2, p3, ))
            print(y)
```

which is really slow for the calculation I'm doing, but I haven't found any better so far. So, does anyone know a way or a package that would allow me to improve the efficiency?

Comment: Have you looked at the optimization statistics for different values of `p1,p2,p3`?  Presumably `minimize` takes a different optimal route to each solution, with different numbers of iterations, and trial values.  So it could be sub-optimal to try to minimize several sets of parameters at once.

Comment: Can't you skip the `c` loop?  The solution doesn't differ for the two values, does it?  And I suspect the solutions might scale with the `a/b` ratio, or something like that.  I may be wrong about those intuitions, but in any case, a little precalculation math might help you reduce the iteration space.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I probably haven't explained myself properly: this is a simplified example, the actual calculation is much more computationally demanding. I'll try to make this more clear in the text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a combination of different techniques to improve the efficiency of your script:

1. Use `itertools.product` to generate every possible combination in the list `a, b, c`
2. Use `multiprocessing`to execute the minimizations in parallel.

Other than this, i can't think of a way to optimize the efficiency of the code. As was pointed out in the comment, the constant value c has no influence on the minimization. But i'm sure the quadratic function is just an example.

I took the code of the multiprocessing part from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874756/parallel-optimizations-in-scipy).

Here's the working code.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x, a, b, c):
    f = a * x**2 + b * x + c
    return f

def mini(args):
    res = opt.minimize(f, x0=np.array([0]), args=args)
    return res.x

if __name__=="__main__":
    a = np.linspace(-1,2,100)
    b = np.linspace(0,2,100)
    c = [0, 1]
    args = list(itertools.product(a,b,c))
    print("Number of combos:" + str(len(args)))
    p = Pool(4)
    import time
    t0 = time.time()
    res = p.map(mini, args)
    print(time.time()-t0)
```

Even these 20000 combinations only need 5,28 seconds on my average laptop.

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.optimize.newton` can do this.