# Parallelization in scipy optimizer

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing

I want to parallelize external runs inside my Scipy minimizer (scipy.optimize.minimize), but methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874756/parallel-optimizations-in-scipy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874756/parallel-optimizations-in-scipy/12874964#12874964) run my original script from scratch for the number of cores requested. Is there any method to parallelize a portion of a function fed to the minimizer, rather than the whole?

To elaborate more, I have a function (F_1) which has another function (F_2) embedded in it and runs it for a range of numbers (a_1 to b_1). F_2 in return calls an external script and runs it (LAMMPS if you must know):

here is F_2:

```
def F_2(X, i):
  # after a series of other stuff, it simply calls an external script and runs it
  lmp = lammps()
  lmp.file("my_other_script_address")
```

here is F_1:

```
def F_1(X_1, a_1, b_1):
  for i in range(a_1, b_1):
    F_2(X_1, i)
  return result
```

now I use a minimizer which works perfectly when running linearly.

```
Minimized = minimize(F_1, X_1, args=Arguments, method='Nelder-Mead')
```

the bottleneck of this minimization is running the external script for the specified range (a_1 to b_1). However, using the pool method or ProcessPoolExecutor runs my original script from scratch for the number of cores requested.

```
def F_1(X_1, a_1, b_1):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                  Running = [executor.submit(F_2, i) for i in range(a_1,b_1)]
  return result
```

Comment: `However, using the pool method or ProcessPoolExecutor runs my original script from scratch` Are you using `if __name__ == '__main__':` ? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360686/compulsory-usage-of-if-name-main-in-windows-while-using-multiprocessi

Comment: @NickODell I have used it as well. Inside F_1:
`if __name__ == '__main__':
pool = mp.Pool(processes=CoreNumber)
pool.map(F_2, RunningRange)`